# Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() gives different value than before converting to string

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, password-hash, sha512

I'm trying to write password hashing code and encountered a problem with hashing methods, then created this test code to see what exactly is happening.

The method first generates a password salt and hash as `byte` arrays using `HMACSHA512`, then converts both values to strings, then converts them back to `byte` arrays.

```
string password = "xxx";

byte[] pswSalt;
byte[] pswHash;

using (HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512())
{
    pswSalt = hmac.Key;
    pswHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
}

var saltAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pswSalt);
var hashAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pswHash);

var pswSaltFromString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltAsString);
var pswHashFromString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashAsString);
```

To my surprise, the final byte arrays are different than the original ones. Why is that? And how do I correct this?
[image]

Comment: (I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate, but I can't find one at the moment.)

Answer (score 3):

Arbitrary byte sequences cannot be converted to Unicode and back. Some byte sequences are not valid as Unicode, and some may be normalised to different sequences.

Base64 can be used if it is really necessary to use strings to represent bytes.

Note that you can store byte arrays in a database, so you don't need a string for that purpose, e.g., in MySQL you might use the [`VARBINARY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) database type.

Comment: If you add some example code for others who come here looking for the solution, I'll happily mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Alternatively you can create your own code, add it to the answer and then accept it. We're not here to do your chores.

Comment: @Val I'm not in a position to check any code I write at the moment, and the question wasn't actually about that ;)

Comment: @Val Also, if this is for a real application, please consider using something like PBKDF2 instead of HMACSHA512 - see [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for a good explanation. Even back in 2013, "as a general rule, HMACSHA512 is not good enough for password hashes": [HMACSHA512 versus Rfc2898DeriveBytes for password hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35250/hmacsha512-versus-rfc2898derivebytes-for-password-hash#comment54798_35250).